# pytest xdist crashes while executing test cases with multiple process

Tags: python, pytest

The test runs fine without `pytest-xdist`'s `-n` parameter.

However, when I execute it with multiple process i.e `-n 10`, it fails with the following traceback

```
INTERNALERROR> Traceback (most recent call last):
INTERNALERROR>   File "c:\jay\work\automation\pytest-splunk-addon\new_dev_environment\pyparallel\lib\site-packages\_pytest\main.py", line 191, in wrap_session
INTERNALERROR>     session.exitstatus = doit(config, session) or 0
INTERNALERROR>   File "c:\jay\work\automation\pytest-splunk-addon\new_dev_environment\pyparallel\lib\site-packages\_pytest\main.py", line 247, in _main
INTERNALERROR>     config.hook.pytest_runtestloop(session=session)
INTERNALERROR>   File "c:\jay\work\automation\pytest-splunk-addon\new_dev_environment\pyparallel\lib\site-packages\pluggy\hooks.py", line 286, in __call__
INTERNALERROR>     return self._hookexec(self, self.get_hookimpls(), kwargs)
INTERNALERROR>   File "c:\jay\work\automation\pytest-splunk-addon\new_dev_environment\pyparallel\lib\site-packages\pluggy\manager.py", line 93, in _hookexec
INTERNALERROR>     return self._inner_hookexec(hook, methods, kwargs)
INTERNALERROR>   File "c:\jay\work\automation\pytest-splunk-addon\new_dev_environment\pyparallel\lib\site-packages\pluggy\manager.py", line 87, in <lambda>
INTERNALERROR>     firstresult=hook.spec.opts.get("firstresult") if hook.spec else False,
INTERNALERROR>   File "c:\jay\work\automation\pytest-splunk-addon\new_dev_environment\pyparallel\lib\site-packages\pluggy\callers.py", line 208, in _multicall
INTERNALERROR>     return outcome.get_result()
INTERNALERROR>   File "c:\jay\work\automation\pytest-splunk-addon\new_dev_environment\pyparallel\lib\site-packages\pluggy\callers.py", line 80, in get_result
INTERNALERROR>     raise ex[1].with_traceback(ex[2])
INTERNALERROR>   File "c:\jay\work\automation\pytest-splunk-addon\new_dev_environment\pyparallel\lib\site-packages\pluggy\callers.py", line 187, in _multicall
INTERNALERROR>     res = hook_impl.function(*args)
INTERNALERROR>   File "c:\jay\work\automation\pytest-splunk-addon\new_dev_environment\pyparallel\lib\site-packages\xdist\dsession.py", line 112, in pytest_runtestloop
INTERNALERROR>     self.loop_once()
INTERNALERROR>   File "c:\jay\work\automation\pytest-splunk-addon\new_dev_environment\pyparallel\lib\site-packages\xdist\dsession.py", line 135, in loop_once
INTERNALERROR>     call(**kwargs)
INTERNALERROR>   File "c:\jay\work\automation\pytest-splunk-addon\new_dev_environment\pyparallel\lib\site-packages\xdist\dsession.py", line 177, in worker_workerfinished
INTERNALERROR>     assert not crashitem, (crashitem, node)
INTERNALERROR> AssertionError: ('tests/test_my_addon.py::Test_App::test_props_fields_positive[splunkd::field::extractthree]', <WorkerController gw7>)
```

I know the solution can be very specific to my implementation. But I just want to know what is the possible reason it went wrong. I tried finding shared objects/dependency among test cases but I couldn't find any.

What can be the possible reasons for this error? Any high-level steps to find out in the current implementation?

**Edit**

Specific to my scenario, I have narrowed down the issue. In my current implementation, I am using a class to represent an object. It doesn't any methods or anything. I have created this class just to make it as a standard for each test case being executed.

```
class Field(object):
    """
        Contains the field properties

        Args:
            field_json (dict): dictionary containing field properties 
    """

    def __init__(self, field_json=None):
        self.name = field_json.get("name")
        self.field_type = field_json.get("field_type")
        self.expected_values = field_json.get("expected_values", ["*"])
        self.negative_values = field_json.get("negative_values", ["-", ""])
        self.condition = field_json.get("condition", ["-", ""])
        self.validity = field_json.get("validity", "")

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

My test case is parametrized with a list of Fields. The problem seemed to be with it. as soon as I removed the class and used a dictionary, the tests started working fine.

Comment: You are right, the error is too generic to say something in particular (a worker has crashed b/c an exception was raised), so please provide a [mcve].

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Believe me, I am trying exactly the same, to find a minimal reproducible example. But even to do that, I would need to narrow down the possibilities. And to narrow down, I need possible reasons for this error.  In short, as soon as I find minimal reproducible example, the issue will be solved for me :)

Comment: Yeah, I've been there quite often - breakpoints in every plugin hookimpl/function, check what is visited last and debug that.